# HaProxy drop CONNECT requests

Tags: haproxy

We get audited by a outside company that does a

```
CONNECT domain.com:80 HTTP/1.0
```

Right now haproxy is the first one taking the request and it is returning a 502 error. The audit company expects a 4xx return code.

The server isn't set to proxy anything but the company things it is allowing it.. any way in haproxy to work around this.

Nginx on the backend is handling the request ok and returning a 400 but then when it is passed back to haproxy its switching it to a 502 for some reason

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ok in classic fashion I found the answer digging through the docs after trying for 2 hours before I posted this

```
block if METH_CONNECT
```

Comment: This isn't normal, but on meth, it is.